# Format list of items with columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I have a long items list:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <!-- various number of items -->
</ul>
```

How can I render this list with columns? **Filling columns first**.

```
Item 1 | Item 5
Item 2 | Item 6
Item 3 | Item 7
Item 4 |
```

Number of columns must be also variable (for responsive layout).

I use TailwindCSS framework.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap or any other CSS framework?

Comment: TailwindCSS framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add media queries if you need to change the number of columns for different devices

```css
ul{
display:inline-block;
column-count:2;
column-gap:10vw;
list-style-type:none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
  <!-- various number of items -->
</ul>
```

Comment: I think this has low browser support. Is there any other way to make it with grids?

Comment: column support was added with chrome 50.  We are now on chrome version 88.  Think you are good to go there